# Query the AAD Graph API as a specific user

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

- I have a webapi which is being called on behalf of a user by a service.
- I have the users Id, but not their auth token.

**My objective to to check if this user belongs to a specified group.**

- I have an application, and can auth against the graph, buy my claims are limited by my organization so I cannot query the Users.
- I created a service account which should have access to the graph API.
- I am working off this example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/blob/master/GraphConsoleAppV3/AuthenticationHelper.cs

I am trying to connect to the graph with the service account, but I'm not sure how. I've tried looking at `UserPasswordCredential` but `AcquireTokenAsync` doesn't take that as an argument but it does take a `UserAssertion` I'm having trouble finding documentation on proper construction of that object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to query as that user? why can't you just query getMemberGroups? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getMemberGroups

Comment: @4c74356b41 I want to query as my service account to check if that user belongs to a group. I don't want to query as that user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were developing with .Net Framework, the `AcquireTokenAsync` do provide the methed using the `UserPasswordCredential`.

Here is the code sample for your reference:

```
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(UserModeConstants.AuthString, false);
string resrouce = "";
string clientId = "";
string userName = "";
string password = "";
UserPasswordCredential userPasswordCredential = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password);
var token= authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resrouce, clientId, userPasswordCredential).Result.AccessToken;
```

I am using the version `3.13.5.907` Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory. And this method only work for the native client application you register on Azure AD since it doesn't provide the credential. If you want it work for the web application/web API, you can make a HTTP request directly like below:

```
POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
resource={resource}&client_id={clientId}&grant_type=password&username={userName}&password={password}&scope=openid&client_secret={clientSecret}
```

Comment: This does work except I need my service account to give permission to the application. Any thoughts on how to do this simply.

Comment: Did you mean that you want to the application to access the resource as itself instead of service account? If I understood correctly, instead of using **Resource Owner Password Credentials**, we need to use the **Client Credentials**. More detail about this flow, you can refer the link [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only).

Comment: oh, no, my application doesn't have the required delegated permissions to do what I need, so I was trying to log in as the service account, but the service account hasn't authorized the application to act on its behalf. :)

Comment: What's the detail error message you have got for this issue?

Comment: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

Comment: result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientId, new Uri(redirectUrl), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)).Result;This will prompt for consent